# g++ help linking with a local copy

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, g++, glew

I am working from my schools computer in ubuntu linux and was wondering what I need to do to link a local copy of GLEW in my project.  My school's computers has SDL GL and GLU installed of course so linking with them is easy, but they do not have a copy of GLEW installed and I don't have the user rights to move my compiled GLEW into the appropriate folders for easy linking.  So I have my test source folder setup with like this:

```
glew
    include
    lib
    ...
main.cpp
```

and I'm using this include statement `#include "glew/include/GL/glew.h"` but I don't know how to link with the lib on a local level so I get errors from g++ saying that `glewInit()` is undefined.  My question is how do I link with my local copy of GLEW this way, or any other way that does not involve something that might require me to be a privileged user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `GCC` there is special `-L` command line parameter to [specify custom path to libraries](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options).

So, you need to add something like `-L./GLEW/lib` into `g++` link command line

Comment: hmmm let me give it a try, i usually use g++.

Comment: It still saying undefined reference to glewInit(), im using gcc -lSDL -Lglew/include -Lglew/lib -lGL -lGLU src.cpp -o test

Comment: add -lglew (or how it is called in lib.

Comment: @HaywireSpark Well, if you need to use a library, usually you need to add the library into linker command line. `gcc -lSDL -Lglew/include -Lglew/lib -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW src.cpp -o test`

Comment: @qehgt that works, but i still get an error saying its missing shared file `libGLEW.so.1.9`, but that can't be right can it?  That file is inside `glew/lib` and i already linked with it using `-Lglew/lib`.

Comment: try to run your application this way: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./glew/lib ./test` It allows to search for dynamic libraries (`*.so`) in `./glew/lib` directory

Comment: @qehgt ok, that also works, but it says its missing the GL version now.